# How to copy/overwrite an object using Object.assign() function?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to fully copy / overwrite an object using Object.assign()?
If there would be another approach, it would be highly appreciated. :)
The purpose is to update the existing object to its new value.

Below is my code snippet and the expected result should be the same as the value of object2 only.

> Expected result: { a: 8, b: 7 }

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: 3
  }
};

const object2 = {
  a: 8,
  b: 7
};

Object.assign(object1, object2);

console.log(object1);
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want to copy `object2` and completely discard the existing `object1`? You shouldn't use `Object.assign` for that

Comment: note that you can't completely replace `object1` since it was declared with `const`.

Comment: Where do any arrays come into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keeping the same object reference, you could remove all properties in advance and then assign the wanted properties with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3 } };
const object2 = { a: 8, b: 7 };

Object.assign(
    Object.keys(object1).reduce((o, k) => (Reflect.deleteProperty(o, k), o), object1),
    object2
);

console.log(object1);
```

IE

```js
var object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 3 } },
    object2 = { a: 8, b: 7 };

Object.keys(object2).reduce(
    function (object, key) {
        object[key] = object2[key];
        return object;
    }, 
    Object.keys(object1).reduce(function (object, key) {
        delete object[key];
        return object;
    }, object1)
);

console.log(object1);
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz, i found out that deleteProperty is not supported in IE :( 
is there any other option which works also in IE?

Comment: it does not support `const` and arrow functions as well, nor `Object.assign`.

Comment: Wow! I tried the other one for IE and it works! thank you so much again!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the `object1` properties with those from `object2`, you need to do it like this:

```
object1 = Object.assign({}, object2);
```

But with this you need to declare `object1` with `var` keyword so you can assign a new value to it.

**Demo:**

```js
var object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: 3
  }
};

const object2 = {
  a: 8,
  b: 7
};

object1 = Object.assign({}, object2);

console.log(object1);
```

Comment: @KimCindy LikeI said, you need to change the declaration from `const object1 = ` to `var object1=`, check the Demo on my answer.

Comment: Yes, on my project it was not declared as const. I tried but the source object doesn't update.